# How to compute the decrease in impurity in tree regression?

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I fitted a regression tree using `rpart` function. The summary of this model is provided below. I need to know how to calculate the decrease in impurity in each node. For example, in the node number 1, how to obtain `improve=0.27435110`? What about `improve=0.14323610` in the node number 2?

Code:

```
library(ISLR)
set.seed(123456)
n=nrow(Carseats)
id.train=sample(1:n,size=300)
id.test=setdiff(1:n,id.train)
Carseat.train=Carseats[id.train,]
Carseat.test=Carseats[id.test,]
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
mytree.reg = rpart(Sales~., data=Carseat.train, method = "anova")
prp(mytree.reg,extra=1,roundint=FALSE)
mytree.reg
summary(mytree.reg)
```

Output:

```
Call:
rpart(formula = Sales ~ ., data = Carseat.train, method = "anova")
  n= 300 

           CP nsplit rel error    xerror       xstd
1  0.27435112      0 1.0000000 1.0077435 0.08255353
2  0.07959254      1 0.7256489 0.7325355 0.05989956
3  0.06932427      2 0.6460563 0.7087161 0.05668191
4  0.05309323      3 0.5767321 0.6872537 0.05329518
5  0.03058940      4 0.5236388 0.6127103 0.04785196
6  0.03047785      5 0.4930494 0.6107188 0.04421544
7  0.02891278      6 0.4625716 0.6107188 0.04421544
8  0.02703786      7 0.4336588 0.6072395 0.04438192
9  0.02355029      8 0.4066209 0.5940172 0.04378300
10 0.01570255      9 0.3830707 0.5828484 0.04188387
11 0.01535808     10 0.3673681 0.5426513 0.03687337
12 0.01208271     11 0.3520100 0.5396221 0.03685969
13 0.01112882     12 0.3399273 0.5461840 0.03856361
14 0.01000000     13 0.3287985 0.5396450 0.03957813

Variable importance
  ShelveLoc       Price   CompPrice         Age Advertising      Income  Population   Education       Urban 
         37          26          11          10           6           4           3           2           1 

Node number 1: 300 observations,    complexity param=0.2743511
  mean=7.469433, MSE=8.366705 
  left son=2 (233 obs) right son=3 (67 obs)
  Primary splits:
      ShelveLoc   splits as  LRL,       improve=0.27435110, (0 missing)
      Price       < 94.5  to the right, improve=0.11027280, (0 missing)
      Advertising < 7.5   to the left,  improve=0.08093875, (0 missing)
      Age         < 61.5  to the right, improve=0.06584917, (0 missing)
      Income      < 59.5  to the left,  improve=0.03800651, (0 missing)

Node number 2: 233 observations,    complexity param=0.07959254
  mean=6.656996, MSE=5.986038 
  left son=4 (70 obs) right son=5 (163 obs)
  Primary splits:
      Price       < 127   to the right, improve=0.14323610, (0 missing)
      Advertising < 7.5   to the left,  improve=0.08230976, (0 missing)
      Age         < 50.5  to the right, improve=0.08004587, (0 missing)
      ShelveLoc   splits as  L-R,       improve=0.06535758, (0 missing)
      Income      < 59.5  to the left,  improve=0.05481430, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      CompPrice   < 136.5 to the right, agree=0.747, adj=0.157, (0 split)
      Advertising < 24.5  to the right, agree=0.708, adj=0.029, (0 split)

Node number 3: 67 observations,    complexity param=0.05309323
  mean=10.29478, MSE=6.367762 
  left son=6 (45 obs) right son=7 (22 obs)
  Primary splits:
      Price       < 109.5 to the right, improve=0.3123584, (0 missing)
      Age         < 62.5  to the right, improve=0.1799132, (0 missing)
      Advertising < 0.5   to the left,  improve=0.1504399, (0 missing)
      Education   < 11.5  to the right, improve=0.1427603, (0 missing)
      US          splits as  LR,        improve=0.1328842, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      CompPrice  < 113.5 to the right, agree=0.731, adj=0.182, (0 split)
      Education  < 11.5  to the right, agree=0.716, adj=0.136, (0 split)
      Population < 490   to the left,  agree=0.701, adj=0.091, (0 split)
      Age        < 26.5  to the right, agree=0.701, adj=0.091, (0 split)

Node number 4: 70 observations,    complexity param=0.02891278
  mean=5.244, MSE=4.430067 
  left son=8 (58 obs) right son=9 (12 obs)
  Primary splits:
      CompPrice   < 147.5 to the left,  improve=0.23402230, (0 missing)
      Advertising < 7.5   to the left,  improve=0.14018930, (0 missing)
      Age         < 66.5  to the right, improve=0.10331410, (0 missing)
      Price       < 155.5 to the right, improve=0.08588524, (0 missing)
      ShelveLoc   splits as  L-R,       improve=0.06034277, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      Price < 158.5 to the left,  agree=0.843, adj=0.083, (0 split)

Node number 5: 163 observations,    complexity param=0.06932427
  mean=7.263804, MSE=5.428614 
  left son=10 (93 obs) right son=11 (70 obs)
  Primary splits:
      Age         < 52.5  to the right, improve=0.19664570, (0 missing)
      CompPrice   < 123.5 to the left,  improve=0.13805010, (0 missing)
      Price       < 94.5  to the right, improve=0.11694370, (0 missing)
      ShelveLoc   splits as  L-R,       improve=0.09405656, (0 missing)
      Advertising < 7.5   to the left,  improve=0.09013121, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      CompPrice   < 124.5 to the left,  agree=0.644, adj=0.171, (0 split)
      Population  < 366   to the left,  agree=0.613, adj=0.100, (0 split)
      Price       < 118.5 to the left,  agree=0.613, adj=0.100, (0 split)
      Urban       splits as  RL,        agree=0.607, adj=0.086, (0 split)
      Advertising < 17    to the left,  agree=0.589, adj=0.043, (0 split)

Node number 6: 45 observations,    complexity param=0.0305894
  mean=9.308667, MSE=4.882012 
  left son=12 (36 obs) right son=13 (9 obs)
  Primary splits:
      Advertising < 13.5  to the left,  improve=0.3494905, (0 missing)
      US          splits as  LR,        improve=0.3074689, (0 missing)
      Age         < 68.5  to the right, improve=0.2486255, (0 missing)
      Price       < 142.5 to the right, improve=0.2430064, (0 missing)
      Population  < 345.5 to the left,  improve=0.1431541, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      Population < 345.5 to the left,  agree=0.844, adj=0.222, (0 split)

Node number 7: 22 observations
  mean=12.31182, MSE=3.349315 

Node number 8: 58 observations,    complexity param=0.01570255
  mean=4.780862, MSE=3.602473 
  left son=16 (8 obs) right son=17 (50 obs)
  Primary splits:
      Price       < 153   to the right, improve=0.18863270, (0 missing)
      Advertising < 7.5   to the left,  improve=0.16887790, (0 missing)
      Age         < 66.5  to the right, improve=0.14124810, (0 missing)
      Income      < 89    to the left,  improve=0.10139480, (0 missing)
      ShelveLoc   splits as  L-R,       improve=0.07263291, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      CompPrice < 140.5 to the right, agree=0.879, adj=0.125, (0 split)
      Income    < 24.5  to the left,  agree=0.879, adj=0.125, (0 split)
      Age       < 27.5  to the left,  agree=0.879, adj=0.125, (0 split)

Node number 9: 12 observations
  mean=7.4825, MSE=2.382485 

Node number 10: 93 observations,    complexity param=0.03047785
  mean=6.367419, MSE=4.40686 
  left son=20 (85 obs) right son=21 (8 obs)
  Primary splits:
      Price       < 80.5  to the right, improve=0.18665850, (0 missing)
      CompPrice   < 123.5 to the left,  improve=0.11170650, (0 missing)
      ShelveLoc   splits as  L-R,       improve=0.11040370, (0 missing)
      Income      < 98.5  to the left,  improve=0.06567414, (0 missing)
      Advertising < 9.5   to the left,  improve=0.06013860, (0 missing)

Node number 11: 70 observations,    complexity param=0.02355029
  mean=8.454714, MSE=4.300305 
  left son=22 (24 obs) right son=23 (46 obs)
  Primary splits:
      Income      < 59.5  to the left,  improve=0.1963698, (0 missing)
      Price       < 104.5 to the right, improve=0.1876723, (0 missing)
      Advertising < 6.5   to the left,  improve=0.1325807, (0 missing)
      US          splits as  LR,        improve=0.1297848, (0 missing)
      CompPrice   < 132.5 to the left,  improve=0.1041169, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      Population < 495   to the right, agree=0.686, adj=0.083, (0 split)

Node number 12: 36 observations,    complexity param=0.01208271
  mean=8.655556, MSE=3.545564 
  left son=24 (16 obs) right son=25 (20 obs)
  Primary splits:
      Advertising < 1     to the left,  improve=0.2376032, (0 missing)
      US          splits as  LR,        improve=0.2347884, (0 missing)
      Price       < 142.5 to the right, improve=0.2299657, (0 missing)
      Age         < 66.5  to the right, improve=0.1943295, (0 missing)
      Education   < 14.5  to the left,  improve=0.1866195, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      Education  < 13.5  to the left,  agree=0.722, adj=0.375, (0 split)
      Income     < 36    to the left,  agree=0.639, adj=0.187, (0 split)
      Population < 117   to the left,  agree=0.611, adj=0.125, (0 split)
      Price      < 142.5 to the right, agree=0.611, adj=0.125, (0 split)
      Age        < 61.5  to the right, agree=0.611, adj=0.125, (0 split)

Node number 13: 9 observations
  mean=11.92111, MSE=1.696721 

Node number 16: 8 observations
  mean=2.72, MSE=5.513625 

Node number 17: 50 observations
  mean=5.1106, MSE=2.508418 

Node number 20: 85 observations,    complexity param=0.02703786
  mean=6.089176, MSE=3.781288 
  left son=40 (28 obs) right son=41 (57 obs)
  Primary splits:
      ShelveLoc   splits as  L-R,       improve=0.21114920, (0 missing)
      CompPrice   < 103.5 to the left,  improve=0.14540380, (0 missing)
      Age         < 71.5  to the right, improve=0.05445243, (0 missing)
      Education   < 10.5  to the right, improve=0.04361708, (0 missing)
      Advertising < 7.5   to the left,  improve=0.03115380, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      Price       < 85.5  to the left,  agree=0.706, adj=0.107, (0 split)
      CompPrice   < 105   to the left,  agree=0.694, adj=0.071, (0 split)
      Advertising < 14.5  to the right, agree=0.682, adj=0.036, (0 split)
      Age         < 56.5  to the left,  agree=0.682, adj=0.036, (0 split)

Node number 21: 8 observations
  mean=9.32375, MSE=1.491098 

Node number 22: 24 observations,    complexity param=0.01112882
  mean=7.1825, MSE=3.200719 
  left son=44 (10 obs) right son=45 (14 obs)
  Primary splits:
      CompPrice   < 118.5 to the left,  improve=0.3636353, (0 missing)
      Price       < 109   to the right, improve=0.2058881, (0 missing)
      Advertising < 4.5   to the left,  improve=0.1817686, (0 missing)
      ShelveLoc   splits as  L-R,       improve=0.1777220, (0 missing)
      US          splits as  LR,        improve=0.1302964, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      Income     < 26.5  to the left,  agree=0.750, adj=0.4, (0 split)
      Age        < 31    to the left,  agree=0.750, adj=0.4, (0 split)
      Price      < 84    to the left,  agree=0.708, adj=0.3, (0 split)
      ShelveLoc  splits as  L-R,       agree=0.708, adj=0.3, (0 split)
      Population < 59    to the left,  agree=0.667, adj=0.2, (0 split)

Node number 23: 46 observations,    complexity param=0.01535808
  mean=9.118478, MSE=3.588969 
  left son=46 (23 obs) right son=47 (23 obs)
  Primary splits:
      Price       < 105   to the right, improve=0.23349900, (0 missing)
      Advertising < 2.5   to the left,  improve=0.12124870, (0 missing)
      CompPrice   < 132.5 to the left,  improve=0.10978950, (0 missing)
      US          splits as  LR,        improve=0.10319700, (0 missing)
      Education   < 15.5  to the right, improve=0.07841711, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      CompPrice   < 121.5 to the right, agree=0.761, adj=0.522, (0 split)
      Income      < 103.5 to the left,  agree=0.587, adj=0.174, (0 split)
      Advertising < 7.5   to the left,  agree=0.587, adj=0.174, (0 split)
      Population  < 157   to the left,  agree=0.587, adj=0.174, (0 split)
      Education   < 14.5  to the left,  agree=0.587, adj=0.174, (0 split)

Node number 24: 16 observations
  mean=7.629375, MSE=3.207881 

Node number 25: 20 observations
  mean=9.4765, MSE=2.299323 

Node number 40: 28 observations
  mean=4.814286, MSE=4.041789 

Node number 41: 57 observations
  mean=6.715439, MSE=2.462702 

Node number 44: 10 observations
  mean=5.906, MSE=2.384784 

Node number 45: 14 observations
  mean=8.094286, MSE=1.788282 

Node number 46: 23 observations
  mean=8.203043, MSE=2.027195 

Node number 47: 23 observations
  mean=10.03391, MSE=3.474702
```

Comment: Can you attach the result object by wrapping in in `dput()`?

Comment: @GiulioCentorame Thanks for your time and consideration. Sorry, I edited my post and provided the reproducible code.

Comment: Thank you. Is the question on how `rpart()` calculates the improvement or how you can obtain the `improve` for each node?

Comment: @GiulioCentorame Both. I need to know how `rpart()` calculates the improvement and I should manually obtain the improve for each node. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For this kind of questions [Crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) would be the correct community